# Parse Date and Time String to only use the Date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this value

```
"6/19/2012 5:16:26 PM"
```

I am wanting to always only show the date and never the time

result i want

```
"6/19/2012"
```

I was trying things like this but it is not at all what i want

```
var myDate="26-02-2012";
myDate=myDate.split("-");
var newDate=myDate[1]+","+myDate[0]+","+myDate[2];
alert(new Date(newDate).getTime());​
```

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787271/extract-date-and-time-from-string-using-javascript

Comment: Are you also using jQuery UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wanting to always only show the date and never the time
>
> result i want
>
> `"6/19/2012"`

Try using `.split()` with `RegExp` `/\s/` , alternatively with `String` `" "` selecting item at index `0` of resulting array

```
  var str = "6/19/2012 5:16:26 PM";
  var date = str.split(/\s/)[0]; // `str.split(" ")[0]`
```

Comment: 1340089200000  is what that gives , I want   6/19/2012

Comment: @MillRunner _"1340089200000 is what that gives , I want 6/19/2012"_ See updated post

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alert(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10));
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h0tv3qb1/)**

Answer (score 1):

use default constructor of `Date`

```
var date = new Date('6/19/2012 5:16:26 PM')
date .getMonth() + "/" date .getDay() + "/" + date .getYear()
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, the output depends on your local settings, is short, uses the Javascript Date API and no String manipulation is needed.

```
(new Date("6/19/2012 5:16:26 PM")).toLocaleDateString() // Output => "6/19/2012"
```

Here a link to the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

And Here a Demo:

```js
document.write((new Date).toLocaleDateString()); // Output => "10/13/2015"    
document.write("<br />");
document.write((new Date("6/19/2012 5:16:26 PM")).toLocaleDateString());  // Output => "6/19/2012"
// tested on Win7 with Chrome 45+
```

Comment: new Date('6/19/2012 5:16:26 PM').toLocaleDateString()

Comment: no, i like you answer. but the first not-edited answer not have contractor for date. I liked to make your answer good than what was it :)

Comment: the problem here is the worst answer is accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

> result i want
>
> "6/19/2012"

If that's *really* what you want, then it's a string, so it's just:

```
var result = "6/19/2012 5:16:26 PM".split(" ")[0];
```

**Live Example:**

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "6/19/2012 5:16:26 PM".split(" ")[0];
```

But if you want an actual `Date` instance, instead of using the one-argument version of `Date`, use the multi-argument version (accepts year, month, day, ...):

```
var myDate="6/19/2012 5:16:26 PM";
myDate=myDate.split(" ")[0].split("/");
alert(new Date(parseInt(myDate[2], 10), parseInt(myDate[0], 10) - 1, parseInt(myDate[1], 10)));​
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var myDate = "6/19/2012 5:16:26 PM";
myDate = myDate.split(" ")[0].split("/");
document.body.innerHTML = new Date(parseInt(myDate[2], 10), parseInt(myDate[0], 10) - 1, parseInt(myDate[1], 10));
```

The `parseInt(..., 10)` converts from string to number using base 10 (decimal), and that builds a date from just the year, month (they start at 0), and day.

Comment: @MillRunner: Oh now that's just embarrassing. That's what you get when you edit without thinking. :-) Thanks.