# datetime convert to date string - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date

I have following datetime value in a json :

```
Fri Jan 22 2016 14:34:38 GMT-0500
```

I would like to display something like `"January 22, 2016"`

How could I achieve this in javascript. I have JQuery, Extjs libraries available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: check the `moment.js` library, you can then use  `moment("Fri Jan 22 2016 14:34:38 GMT-0500").format("LL")` to get your formatted date

Answer (score 1):

Try creating object having properties of abbreviated months, values of full month, using `for..in` loop , `String.prototype.slice()`, `String.prototype.replace()`

```js
var months = {
 "Jan":"January",
  "Feb":"February",
  "Mar":"March",
  "Apr":"April",
  "May":"May",
  "Jun":"June",
  "Jul":"July",
  "Aug":"August",
  "Sep":"September",
  "Oct":"October",
  "Nov":"November",
  "Dec":"December"
};

var date = "Fri Jan 22 2016 14:34:38 GMT-0500";
// extract "Jan 22 2016" from `date`
var d = date.slice(4, -18);

for (var prop in months) {
  if (new RegExp(prop).test(d)) {
    // replace abbreviated month with full month name
    d = d.replace(prop, months[prop]);
    // replace day with day followed by comma `,` character
    d = d.replace(/(\d{2})(?=\s)/, "$1,")
  }
}

document.body.textContent = d
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is addressed to the same question of yours. You can use the functions shown here to construct the date string as you want.

```
// This could be any Date String
var str = "Fri Feb 08 2013 09:47:57 GMT +0530 (IST)";
var date = new Date(str);
```

This will then give you access to all the Date functions (MDN)

For example:

```
var day = date.getDate(); //Date of the month: 2 in our example
var month = date.getMonth(); //Month of the Year: 0-based index, so 1 in our example
var year = date.getFullYear() //Year: 2013
```

[Extract date and time from string using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787271/extract-date-and-time-from-string-using-javascript)

Comment: @JohnHascall Sorry, new to this. Will remember next time. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, we're all new sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Found this crazy method here, but worked!

[Converting milliseconds to a date (jQuery/JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673527/converting-milliseconds-to-a-date-jquery-js)

Here is the fiddle that i'v done

https://jsfiddle.net/Ripper1992/hj6L2Lvz/

```
var now = new Date("Fri Jan 22 2016 14:34:38 GMT-0500");
alert(now.customFormat( "#MMMM# #DD#, #YYYY#" ) );
```

**customFormat** is the function called to get each part of the Data, parse and replace based on the **#MMMM#** or **#DD#** or **#SS#** defined by the user.

And here is the complete function with the documentation
http://phrogz.net/JS/FormatDateTime_JS.txt